# Howto monitor PermGen space usage before redeploying in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, permgen, redeploy

In order to decide if the jvm is likely to run into a permgen space shortage after the next redeplyoment I'd like to monitor the current permgen space usage before hand

something like:

```
set myPermGenThreshold = 0.51  (51%)
currentlyUsedPermGenSize = (...ask the jvm here... say it's 0.6)

if (currentlyUsedPermGenSize > myPermGenThreshold ) {
 (...restart tomcat...)
}
else {
  (...redeploy application...)
}
```

Comment: Did you look at JMX? There should be a command line client. And it can provide the data I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Memory MX Bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) will give you all non-heap usage, of which the perm gen is a part.  The size of the perm gen pool itself should be available using the [Memory Pool MX Bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html), but be aware that the names of the pools are implementation and GC-dependent.

Both of these JMX beans are available from the platform server, as usual, so they should be obtainable externally using a [JMX client](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html).

Edit - links updated to 1.7.

Comment: Done - our corporate baseline is 1.5; I forget that time (and versions) have moved on.

Comment: [Here](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/download) is a reasonable CLI jmx client.