# Monitoring permgen space

Tags: java, weblogic, monit

I'm looking for an option to monitor perigean space on my web logic server. I would like to use something like monit to check it periodically and restart the service if it gets too large. This is obviously a less than ideal workaround. But, I would like to get a quick fix in while we're looking fro the root cause.

Comment: You can monitor memory usage, incl. Permgen, using JMX. See [Howto monitor PermGen space usage before redeploying in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12086703/5221149). As for finding a tool to do that for you, that is off-topic for StackOverflow, so voting to close as *"**questions asking us to recommend or find** a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: I feel your pain.  One thing you can do is run a version of WebLogic which is compatible with Java 8, since Java 8 has no PermGen space to begin with.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't ask for a tool, I am planning to use mmonit. Just wasn't sure how to gather the data from the command line. Thinks for the suggestion!

Comment: Can mmonit do JMX? If not, then it is not the tool for the job. Unless you have another *tool* that can proxy SNMP to JMX.

Comment: mmonit cannot. But I can create a script that can. And mmonit can call that script.